Is there any information on why ibm is not releasing a new version of cplex?
The last version of cplex that was released is 22.1.1 back in December 2022. Is there any information on the release plan for cplex from ibm?

Explain your need for CPlex and we'll help you find another tool that supports those features.

As indicated in some answers, i also did not expect any improvements to the core solvers for quite some time now, but now it seems even tooling is not developed anymore: supported operating-systems, supported language-wrappers (e.g. Python <= 3.10).

Those that are familiar with the history of Gurobi will know that the reason Gurobi exists is because IBM pumped the brakes on Cplex development.

Most CPLEX developers left IBM in the recent years and went on to develop other solvers like Gurobi or Xpress. It is unlikely that there will be a new release of CPLEX including significant feature updates or improvements anytime soon.
Luckily, Gurobi and other state-of-the-art solvers can do most of the things and more that CPLEX can, so switching should not be too difficult.
Disclaimer: I work for Gurobi.

"Gurobi and other state-of-the-art solvers can do most of the things and more that CPLEX can". According to this, it appears that user defined branching rules which are possible in CPLEX via a branch callback are not supported in Gurobi? I am curious if that is still true as the page I linked to is more than 2 years old? Thank you. I am thinking of switching but am curious about the cost involved and need to learn new ways of doing things.

Indeed, custom branching rules are not supported in Gurobi. The main reason is that the effort to implement and support this largely outweighs the potential performance benefits. Maybe just write a representative set of models from your application and solve them with a trial version of Gurobi to get a better feel for the performance difference.

Related:is it possible to find out which variables GRB has branched on to reach a particular branch&bound node and whether the branching is a <= 0 or a >= 1 type of branch [for binary integer programs] within the MIP tree?In CPLEX, this is possible via a branch callback where CPLEX takes branching decisions and the user can query them [regardless of whether the user subsequently modifies the decisions or not].This seems to suggest this is not possible, but that link is a bit dated, hence the query here.

That information is dated but still correct. You cannot get branching information from Gurobi.

AFAIK, no one is working on it at present. I don't expect any updates. My details are all second-hand, so I won't post them here. If you need a (fast) supported solver with branching/tableau callback support, try Xpress instead.
Also, I think HeuristicCallback.set_solution is broken in CPlex 22.1.1, so be wary of that.

There are groups in IBM that work on development of CPLEX, and also its integration into multiple cloud environments, and how it works with newer technologies like LLM. CPLEX studio is only one of the products that  IBM provides for CPLEX.
Feel free to keep using CPLEX either standalone, or in IBM Cloud!

OP was asking about upcoming releases of CPLEX Optimization Studio (due to concerning inactivity) and while others indirectly answered this (partially) by explaining, that there have been heavy changes to the dev-team with foreseeable consequences, your answer basically only defends against those others ("please keep using it") while not providing any insights irt. the original question (but mentioning irrelevant topics to OPs question). Maybe you can back it up by saying something about upcoming releases?

I would like to reiterate the point raised by the user @sascha.  The issue here is the lack of support for newer versions of supported language wrappers and OS due to non release of cplex versions. And by the look of it, nobody is sure about the roadmap also. This is a worrying sign for current users of cplex optimisation studio

Recently IBM has added the CPLEX to its new cloud platform watsonx that enables integration of CPLEX with LLM applications. More than that, there is a roadmap for updates on CPLEX based on works on IBM Dev and research teams, including adding new capabilities and supporting more OS systems, and performance improvements.
IBM CPLEX has a support here
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/304105
separate from the forum
https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/communities/community-home?CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7
